# Locate digits from right side in Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, substring, trim

I have a column that contains phone numbers in hive. I want to extract the last 4 digits of each number, how is this possible? In MYSQL we can use "RIGHT" but in Hive there isn't an equivalent. The phone number length varies so I cannot use the "Locate" function, but I could be unsure.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out using a combination of the reverse and substring function.

(REVERSE((SUBSTR((REVERSE(d.phone_number)),1,4))))

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function.
As substring function can be applied on string only. You can do

```
cast(int_col as string)
```

Then

```
Substr(col_name,-1*(num of elements))
```

In this case:

```
Substr(d.phone_number,-4)
```